# How do I find the row numbers of a list of values?

Tags: r

I am trying to find approximate 500 IDs in the format of 00567, 00587, 00723 etc from a dataframe with over 10,000 participants.

If I specify a vector with the IDs I need to extract, this does not work in the following;

```
     row_numbers <- which(df$ID %in% vector)
```

It seems I need to individually write out the 500 IDs in

```
  row_numbers <- which(df$ID %in% c("00567", "00587", "00723").
```

However, I don't have the time to write out 500 IDS, I may also get them wrong.

Please could someone specify how I can find the row numbers of a large vector of IDs in a dataframe?

Update (data)

```
  structure(list(ID = c("2111007-00643", "2111007-00644", "2111007-00645", 
  "2111007-00646", "2111007-00647", "2111007-00649", "2111007-00652", 
 "2111007-00653", "2111007-00656", "211107-00658")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

This is a made-up version of my ID numbers which have a dash before the last 5 digits. I have removed the dash from both the data frame and vector of IDS. Making sure both are numeric class. When I use the vector I get 0 row numbers; however, when using the c("ID", "ID") I get row-numbers.

Comment: Could you post sample data as well?

Comment: One possible reason is that you `vector` object is numeric and numeric doesn't allow 0s padded as leading character.  You may need `sprintf('%05d', vector)` or `sprintf('%05s', vector)` depending on the class